# Protecting data on webserver from site grabbers/copiers

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have mp3 files placed on my webserver in the public folder (I am placing it in public folder so that player on my site can access those files), I'm not concerned if a user is able to download an MP3 which he might be able to view, while player is playing that file, however I am also taking care that he is not able to view the direct url to the file. But I want to protect those files from a site grabber software, so that some1 can't steal all the files placed on the server.

The other part of the question is: what is the scope of site grabbing software, can I block them just by turning indexes off for my directories, or can they also have access to files whose urls are not embedded in page ?

Please help

Comment: Have access != can find. Of course any grabber software could just brute-force test all possible file names.

Comment: Thats correct Bergi,
So, what can be the solution that can serve the purpose.
Also i have studied about options like robots.txt file or excluding site grabbers using .htaccess [but all these solutions are not full proof as for that i need to know all the existing softwares avialable]

Comment: If any user of your site has access to the files, every grabber will have too.

Comment: So, is there a way that i can protect those files ?? I can't place them outside root folder, as that will also restrict my player to access those files

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that it's impossible to prevent a user from getting your file. In order to play an audio file, the users web browser has to download it to their local machine.

You could prevent a standard-compliant web grabber from grabbing the file by using a [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) or the `rel="nofollow"` property on hyperlinks, but the interpretation of these is client-sided, so it's possible for the grabber to just ignore them when it feels like it (I once wrote a webgrabber which doesn't even look at these. That was mostly out of laziness, not out of malicious intent).

**tl;dr:** When you don't want people to download a file, don't put it on the Internet.

Comment: Philipp, i have gone through studying robots.txt method, but as you said, it can be easily ignored, but what i want to achieve is what many sites are already using. any of the music sites like saavn.com grooveshark.com, they protect their music form grabbers. How they are doing that ?

Comment: @RohitG Give me a free weekend and I write a grabber for these sites.

Comment: Believe me, it's gonna hurt them big time ;)

Comment: @RohitG It's not like nobody has done it before: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/grooveshredder/

Comment: It's a nice add-on [ofcourse for education purposes only] But,if you read my question again you will see that i am already believing that user may download the file which is being played in the player, but my concern is to protect files from site grabbers that can download all of the files in one go. and also may lead to bandwidth issues and even crashing of server. take the example of you tube where we can easily download the video which is being played but we don't have access to all of them through site grabbers. Hope this will clarify my question/requirement a bit more.

Comment: You could try to limit the number of files an IP address can access in a specific timeframe and not send files to those who exceed their quota. You could do that by wrapping the file download in a PHP script which keeps track of all accesses per IP in a database and only send the file when the user hasn't requested more than X files in the past Y seconds. That won't stop people from ripping individual files, but it would make it harder to rip your whole portfolio (not impossible, though, with enough time and/or proxy servers)